# How to copy the RTV output to the side of a cubemap?

Tags: directx, directx-11, hlsl

I am currently implementing diffuse irridiance(A part of Image based lightning of **PBR**) in my [game engine](https://github.com/FahimFuad/Electro). I got to the point where I have to take an **HDR** Image and turn it into a **cubemap**. I am currently using a EquirectangularToCubemap shader and its working fine. I was able to project the HDR image to a (unit)cube. Now comes the part where I am stuck, I can't turn this cube to a **cubemap**. I tried using **1 TextureCube**, **6 RenderTargetView**'s and a **ShaderResourceView**. My plan was to render the (unit)cube 6 times from different view projection with a **FOV** of 90 to capture the whole side in each of the render target, and lastly ***copy each of the output of the render target to the corresponding side of the Texture cube***.
I don't know how to do this ^.
**NOTE:** I am using DirextX11 as the rendering backend.
Here is the pseudo code about my problem(which is not working)

```cpp
   glm::mat4 captureProjection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), 1.0f, 0.1f, 10.0f);
   glm::mat4 captureViews[] =
    {
        glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f)),
        glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f)),
        glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f)),
        glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f)),
        glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f)),
        glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f))
    };
 
    //Create the TextureCube
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc = {};
    textureDesc.Width = 512;
    textureDesc.Height = 512;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 6;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE;
    ID3D11Texture2D* tex = nullptr;
    DX_CALL(DX11Internal::GetDevice()->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, nullptr, &tex));
    // Create the Shader Resource view for the texture cube
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc = {};
    srvDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURECUBE;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    DX_CALL(DX11Internal::GetDevice()->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &srvDesc, &mSRV));
 
 
    //Create the Render target views
    Vector<ID3D11RenderTargetView*> rtvs;
 
    for (Uint i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc = {};
        renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
        renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
 
        ID3D11RenderTargetView* view = nullptr;
        DX11Internal::GetDevice()->CreateRenderTargetView(tex, &renderTargetViewDesc, &view);
        rtvs.push_back(view);
    }
    tex->Release();
 
    auto deviceContext = DX11Internal::GetDeviceContext();
    for (Uint i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        float clearColor[4] = { 1.0f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f };
        deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(rtvs[i], clearColor);
        Vault::Get<Shader>("EquirectangularToCubemap.hlsl")->Bind();
 
        auto data = captureProjection * captureViews[i];
        cbuffer->Bind();
        cbuffer->SetData(&data);
        texture->Bind(0);
        tempPipeline->Bind();
        deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtvs[i], nullptr);
//I am rendering the cube here from different view projection to capture the faces, but I dont't know where to copy the data to the //side of the TextureCube :( [Note that I am doing this only once]
        RenderCommand::DrawIndexed(tempPipeline, 36);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may find it useful to look at the legacy sample [CubeMapGS](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-legacy-samples/tree/main/Direct3D10/CubeMapGS) which does some fancy stuff with cubemap rendering with Direct3D 10. Direct3D 10 maps pretty directly to DX11 per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3d11-programming-guide-migrating#direct3d-10-to-direct3d-11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying which slices you want to write to when creating render views.
The correct description for slices is:

```
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc = {};
renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DARRAY;
renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2DArray.MipSlice = 0;
renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2DArray.FirstArraySlice =i;
renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2DArray.ArraySize = 1;
```

(Note : if you use MSAA, ViewDimension will become D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMSARRAY)

Also to create the shader view for your resource, since you want to create a default one, you can pass NULL instead of a home made D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC

```
DX_CALL(DX11Internal::GetDevice()->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, NULL, &mSRV));
```

You can also create another render view that maps the whole cube map in one go :

```
DX11Internal::GetDevice()->CreateRenderTargetView(tex, NULL, &cubeMapFullView);
```

But in that case you will need to use Geometry Shader to replicate geometry across slices (using SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex), or use vendor specific extensions that provide the same kind of feature.